# Tabulator: Set focus on the first cell of the first row when table is shown

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I'm new user with tabulator, is really great and first time that I see a library with a good documentation. Congrats !!!

I am making a table with an initial data array set of one item and a default value for date.

What I want is the first cell be foccused the first time the table is displayed.

I have tested with the following events:
rowAdded, tableBuit, dataLoaded, dataProcessed, dataChanged, and renderComplete.

[image]

This is the code: ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Federico_Moon/sp0tz56m/8/))

```js
'use strict';
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;

let dt = DateTime.local();

 class Item {
    constructor() {
        this.id = 0;
        this.name = "";
        this.dob = "";
        this.age = "";
        this.dupdt = "";
    }
}

var tableData = [];

let item = new Item();
item.dupdt = dt.toFormat('dd/MM/yyyy');
tableData.push(item);

var table = new Tabulator("#table", {
    data: tableData,
    layout: "fitColumns",
    addRowPos: "bottom",
    movableColumns: true,
    resizableColumnFit: true,
    tabEndNewRow: function (row) {
        let item = new Item();
        item.dupdt = dt.toFormat('dd/MM/yyyy');

        return item;
    },
    columns: [
        { title: "Id", field: "id", formatter: "rownum", width: 30, minWidth: 30, hozAlign: "center" },
        { title: "Name", field: "name", editor: "input" },
        { title: "Age", field: "age", editor: "number" },
        {
            title: "Date", field: "dupdt", editor: "date", editorParams: {
                format: "dd/MM/yyyy", // the format of the date value stored in the cell
                verticalNavigation: "table", //navigate cursor around table without changing the value
            }
        }
    ],
});

table.on("renderCompleted", function () {
    let row = table.getRowFromPosition(1);

    let cells = row.getCells();
    let el = cells[1].getElement();
    cell.focus();
});
```

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: I just realized my mistake: In the last line instead of el.focus() I have written cell.focus(). Timur's answer is also valid. Thanks Timur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `tableBuilt` event instead and calling `edit` on the cell component should focus the editor.

```
table.on("tableBuilt", function () {
    let row = table.getRowFromPosition(1);

    row.getCell('name').edit();
});
```

Here is an example from a fork of your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vdLatow8/